# Problem accessing $bucket in a function inside a class

Tags: php, couchbase

I am trying to build a reusable db class which allows me to access basic crud function against my couchbase db. When I try to execute this function, I get the following error:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: bucket in
/var/www/html/PHRETS/couchBase.php on line 26 PHP Fatal error: 
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function upsert() on null in
/var/www/html/PHRETS/couchBase.php:26 Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/PHRETS/retsphp.php(72): couchDb::upsert('OpenHouse::b769...', Object(OpenHouse))
#1 {main}   thrown in /var/www/html/PHRETS/couchBase.php on line 26
```

So the question is how can I access the $bucket Object from a function inside a class ?

This is my code in the couchBase.php

```
<?php

use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;
use Ramsey\Uuid\Exception\UnsatisfiedDependencyException;

$bucketName = "default";

// Establish username and password for bucket-access
$authenticator = new \Couchbase\PasswordAuthenticator();
$authenticator->username('Administrator')->password('Password');

// Connect to Couchbase Server - using address of a KV (data) node
$cluster = new CouchbaseCluster("couchbase://127.0.0.1");

// Authenticate, then open bucket
$cluster->authenticate($authenticator);
$bucket = $cluster->openBucket($bucketName);


class couchDb {



    public function upsert($DocId, $doc)
    {
        $result = $bucket->upsert($DocId, $doc);
        return ($result->cas);
    }

}
```

Comment: For starters move your declaration of bucket within your class above the function

Comment: Please note that CouchDB and Couchbase are not the same things, I would recommend renaming your class to avoid confusion

Answer (score 2):

so "$bucket" is not known in the class scope. To use "bucket" in your class you may inject this instance. Please have a look for "[Dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)" like this:

```
class couchDb {
    private $bucket;

    public function __construct(THE_TYPE_WICH_RETURNS_OPENBUCKET $bucket)
    {
        $this->bucket = $bucket;
    }

    public function upsert($DocId, $doc)
    {
        $result = $this->bucket->upsert($DocId, $doc);
        return ($result->cas);
    }

}
```

Comment: How would i find the type to replace the "THE_TYPE_WICH_RETURNS_OPENBUCKET"

Comment: That type hint is not strictly required I don't think, but I think he means it's the type which is returned BY openBucket. That might be "IBucket" or "Bucket".